# Model Relationship Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

I am trying to calculate the average (mean) rating for all entries within a category based on the following model associations ...

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base      
  acts_as_rateable
  belongs_to :category
  ...
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entry
  ...
end


class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

The rating model is handled by the [acts as rateable](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/07/05/acts-as-rateable-plugin/) plugin, so the rateable model looks like this ...

```
  module Rateable #:nodoc:
  ...

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_rateable
        has_many :ratings, :as => :rateable, :dependent => :destroy
        ...
      end
    end
    ...
  end
```

How can I perform the average calculation? Can this be accomplished through the rails model associations or do I have to resort to a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [average](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002188) method is probably what you're looking for. Here's how to use it in your situation:

```
@category.entries.average('ratings.rating', :joins => :ratings)
```

Comment: I am keenly aware of the average method, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this situation. I am interested in finding the average (mean) for all entries within a specific category.

Comment: Of course! Perfect! Thanks. I was beginning to think I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a named_scope or custom method on the model.  Either way it would still require some SQL since, if I understand the question, your are calculating a value.

In a traditional database application this would be a view on the data tables.

So in this context you might do something like... (note not tested or sure it is 100% complete)

```
class Category  
  has_many :entry do  
    def avg_rating()  
       @entries = find :all
       @entres.each do |en|
          @value += en.rating
    end  
    return @value / entries.count
  end


 end
```

Comment: though if you get a AVG group function in SQL it sure will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Check out EmFi's revised answer.

I make no promises but try this

```
class Category
  def average_rating    
    Rating.average :rating, 
      :conditions => [ "type = ? AND entries.category_id = ?", "Entry", id ],
      :join => "JOIN entries ON rateable_id = entries.id"
  end
end
```